# Angular2 RouterLink breaks routes by replacing slash with %2F

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

Since the latest Angular2 version (2.0.0-beta.14) it is possible to have query parameters that contain multiple slashes, like /foo/bar.

This works great, however whenever I use a parameter with multiple slashes within a RouterLink link, it escapes the `/` with `%2F` causing the routes to not work anymore on reload.

My link looks like this: `<a [routerLink]="['/Page', {page: page.url | slug}]" class="list-group-item">{{ page.title }}</a>`

Inside of the 'slug' pipe I even `URIDecode` the string, and when I log it it is correct. It would log something like `/pages/level-1/`, but when I inspect the actual `a` tag on the page it says `href="/pages%2Flevel-1"`.

I'm pretty clueless, because even when I print the value of `{{ page.url | slug }}` within my HTML template, it returns the url with slashes.

Comment: I guess you should create a bug report in http://github.com/angular if possible with a Plunker that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will create a new issue tomorrow.

Comment: I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61021832/271450

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the solution thanks to the Angular2 Issues page on Github (thanks Günter!).

My route was configured like this:

```
({ 
    path: "/:page",
    component: Page,
    name: "Page"
}),
```

but instead should have been

```
({
    path: "/*page",
    component: Page,
    name: "Page"
}),
```

Difference is the `*` wildcard in front of `page`.

I created [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8049)

Comment: Simon Green (CaptainCodeman) is always a great source of knowledge!

Comment: I can't get this to work with child routes.  As soon as I put the * in there, it stops setting the parameter in the code.

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't work, not anymore at least. I'm using Angular Router 7.2.14. And I don't see how this could have ever worked, because once you put the star (*) in front of the parameter, it's not a parameter anymore, but just a string with a wildcard.

Answer (score 11):

You need to replace comma(,) with (+) like this

```
Wrong => <a [routerLink]="['/Page', page.url]" class="list-group-item">{{ page.title }}</a>
Right => <a [routerLink]="['/Page' + page.url]" class="list-group-item">{{ page.title }}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Praveen. I tried different ways, your answer is the easiest and best way to solve this issue.

Comment: your answer works for me ( in my case I am trying to get URL from function and append the string result to a prefix like (  <a [routerLink]="['/Page' + getUtlFunction() ]" class="list-group-item">{{ page.title }}</a> ) )

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to use strings with slashes in routerLink, we simply let the router handle it in the component.

```
<a (click)="goToPage(url)">Link</a>
```

```
url = 'group/8';

goToPage(url) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: it won't work for angular-universal because it replaces all router links with <a href

Comment: Thanks. Finally I used calling a method from a tag and used location.back(). goBack(): void {
    this._location.back();
  }

Comment: Remember that this will this solution will disable the rightclick feature 'Open in new tab' that many user expects.

Answer (score 4):

If the path was something like

```
pathServedByTheController = 'foo/bar'
```

then in the view I can do something like

```
<my-button (click)="onEmitCta()" [routerLink]="['/'].concat(pathServedByTheController.split('/')).concat('')" class="banner-cta inverse shadow">NAVIGATE</my-button>
```

This works nicely to me!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Angular 7 or higher, and the other answers don't work out for you, you might have some problems with your paths.

It works if you define a path with multiple slashes. However, when working with translations, I got an error.

```
[{
  path: 'parentX',
  children: [
   {
     path: 'y/z'
     component: AnyComponent
   }
  ]
}]
```

**All credit goes to Dabbas' question and** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55696188/in-angular-localize-router-if-path-contains-multiple-slashes-change-language-b)

It took me a while to land on his solution, which is why I added it here.

```
[{
  path: 'parentX',
  children: [
   {
     path: 'y',
     children: [
       {
        path: 'z',
        component: AnyComponent
       }
     ]
   }
  ]
}]
```