# Forward Slash in Angular Route Parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How do I set up my routes so that my parameter can take forward slashes?

For example: myapp.com/file/rootfolder/subfolder/myfile

This doesn't work:

```
const SECTION_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'file/:path', component: FileStoreComponent }
];
```

Is having / in routing parameter values possible?

I've read about URL approaches that use URL encoding. However, I'd like my user to be able to type the URL.

Comment: Why not have your user type the url and then URL encode it before submitting it?  You should probably be making the value safe anyways to prevent malicious behavior, just make your URL encoding a part of that function.

Comment: I'd like to make the URL simple to read, like when provided through emails. Is there a way to take the URL and encode it before getting to the router?

Comment: Ah I thought you meant through an input.

Comment: This github issue says you have to escape each forward slash with a wildcard like so `/*page`: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8049.  This issue also covers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597832/angular2-routerlink-breaks-routes-by-replacing-slash-with-2f

Comment: I tried it with 'file/*path'. It's unable to resolve the route... "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: \'file/folder1/folder2/file\'\n" (My Angular version is set to ^4.0.0.0.)

Answer (score 6):

To achieve this with a recent version of Angular (9.X for me), you can use the `Route.matcher` parameter. Here is an example:

```js
function filepathMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[], 
                         group: UrlSegmentGroup, 
                         route: Route) : UrlMatchResult {
  // match urls like "/files/:filepath" where filepath can contain '/'
  if (segments.length > 0) {
    // if first segment is 'files', then concat all the next segments into a single one
    // and return it as a parameter named 'filepath'
    if (segments[0].path == "files") {
      return {
        consumed: segments,
        posParams: {
          filepath: new UrlSegment(segments.slice(1).join("/"), {})
        }
      };
    }
  }
  return null;
}

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { matcher: filepathMatcher, component: FilesComponent },
  // ...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

You will be able to access the parameter in your Component through the `ActivatedRoute.paramMap`

Note the query parameters are also working and preserved.

However, you will still have issues if the URL contains parenthesis, for example `/files/hello(world:12)/test` because they are interpreted by angular as auxiliary routes

In this case, you can add a [custom UrlSerializer](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10280#issuecomment-309129784) to encode parenthesis and you'll have to decode them in your Component.

Comment: maybe you need ```filepath: new UrlSegment(segments.slice(1).map(p=>decodeURIComponent(p.path)).join("/"), {})```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to escape each forward slash with a wildcard like so:

```
/*page
```

This question covers it: [Angular2 RouterLink breaks routes by replacing slash with %2F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597832/angular2-routerlink-breaks-routes-by-replacing-slash-with-2f)

That question links to the following GitHub issue ticket that goes more in-depth: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8049

Comment: %2f comes when space is their

Comment: I tried it with 'file/*path'. It's unable to resolve the route... "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: \'file/folder1/folder2/file\'\n" (My Angular version is set to ^4.0.0.0.)

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this for matching on path `:path`

```
const SECTION_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { 
        matcher: t => t.length ? { consumed: t, posParams: { path: new UrlSegment(t.join('/'), {}) } } : null, 
        component: FileStoreComponent 
    }
];
```

Comment: you forgot t.slice(1) in path

Answer (score -2):

Adding `<base href="/">` to index.html helped me.

Comment: That's not the problem. We are talking about a slash character, which is a reserved character in web / angular. But we want to use a slash while using angular router, but jsust as a editorial character (lets say a headline or maybe a product code). Angular confuses it with the forward slash which signals a router part item, that's why we need some kind of escaping mechanism