# Angular 2.5 How to pass a / in a route parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5

I have googled the issue and have had no luck.

Is it possible to use "/" as part of the route parameter? For example, I have the following route:

```
{
    path: 'pages/:page',
    component: HomeComponent
}
```

I want to pass in `folderName/Page` into the `:page` parameter, so the following:
`/pages/testFolder/testPage` will match on the above route.

I cannot create additional routes because this needs to be dynamic (i.e. `/pages/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/page`).

Please let me know if this is possible.

I have tried steps from [Forward Slash in Angular Route Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810860/forward-slash-in-angular-route-parameters) and have tried using a url-matcher, but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: You could always encode it using `encodeURIComponent`, then decode it in your component

Comment: Angular will actually decode the parameter for you. For example if you pass in `folderName%2FPage` as user184994 recommended. When you pull the parameter `:page` will be `folderName/Page`

Comment: you can use { path: 'pages/:folder/:page', component: MyComponent }. Then in ngOnInit this.route.params.subscribe( params => console.log(params)); //object {folder:textFolder,page:textPage}

Comment: @ user184994 What happens when the user manually types in the URL into the url bar?  they aren't going to type out encoded characters

Comment: @LLai I can't do this, because users can favorite the URLs or type it in manually

Comment: @Eliseo this doesn't solve my issue

Comment: This question could really benefit from some formatting.

Comment: @zze what does that mean

Comment: @drabbitharv - `@ManojChalode` already edited it for you.

Answer (score 4):

you can setup your route like below to resolve your issue,

```
  {
    path: 'pages',
    children: [
      {
        path: "**", component: PagesComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

so what essentially is being done here is any path which starts with pages/... will be intercepted with this route,.

To get different segments from your URL you can use below in your Component,

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
   route.url.subscribe(segments => // use segments as suitable );
}
```

so based on your url, segments will be different,

**route** : /pages/Folder1/Page1

**segments**

```
 [ { "path": "Folder1", "parameters": {} }, { "path": "Page1", "parameters": {} } ]
```

**route**: /pages/Folder2/Folder3/Page1

**segments**

[ { "path": "Folder2", "parameters": {} }, { "path": "Folder3", "parameters": {} }, { "path": "Page1", "parameters": {} } ]

Here is [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-routing-wildcardroutes?file=app/app.module.ts)!!

One thing you have to consider is wild card routes will absorb anything which start with pages/ so make it last.

Comment: this has gotten me closer to a solution.  I would still like to accomplish this the old way (AngularJS could do this fine) but I may be able to make this work.  Still accepting other answers as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, using forward slash as a part of route is always a challenge.

Using a wild card can be one of the options to solve the problem but it sometimes can be dangerous (as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48105325/2332159) answer).

I faced the same problem and I solved it by converting `forward slashes` into `plus sign` in the `URL`.

It allowed me to keep the normal routing configuration and thus the `URL` became readable as well.

To solve the mapping problem, I came up with `route resolvers`.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class PageResolverService implements Resolve<any> {

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        //assuming route is 'pages/:page'
        let path: String = route.params.page.replace('+', '/');
        //API call goes here
    }
}
```

And the routing configuration changed to -

```
{
    path: 'pages/:page',
    component: HomeComponent
    resolve: {
        page: PageResolverService
    }
}
```

In the end I had to handle a corner case scenario where the route name itself has `+` sign in it. Everything else worked fine.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: How would this help an end user?  Let's say I type in the URL manually: pages/folder1/folder2/myPage.  This wouldn't work since the enduser doesn't know he needs to use +

Comment: It seems wild card is the only option available here. Will the URL always have  `pages` route in the beginning? If that is the case, you can use the wild card approach (something like `*pages:folder-path`) to solve the problem as explained in other answer.