# Angular route - how to use forward slashes in routing path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How do I use a path with forward slashes in an Angular route?

Building on the Hero tutorial, I have:

```
{ path: 'detail/:path', component: HeroDetailComponent },
```

Path is meant to be dynamic.  It can be like

```
a/b
a/b/c
a/d/e/f
```

and so on. The point is I don't know how deep the path will be nor what the individual path parts are named.

In the HTML it is used like

```
<a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.path}}">
   {{hero.path}}
</a>
```

Error is

```
Error: Cannot match any routes.
```

The end goal is for the Angular service to use the path in as URL query parameter in a request to the server.

I've tried several hard coded values in the routerLink to ensure the code works if I'm just passing a value without any forward slashes.

I've tried the suggestion here without success: [Forward Slash in Angular Route Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810860/forward-slash-in-angular-route-parameters)

I found https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10570 which seems to describe my issue, and claim it is fixed in 2016.  Some others are claiming it doesn't work in 2017.

I would love it if someone could point me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use property binding `[]` instead of interpolation `{{}}` in your HTML:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/detail', hero.path]">
   {{hero.path}}
</a>
```