# How to use a wild card for part of the path in Angular router?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have the following routing setup.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "submenu1", component: SubmenuComponent, outlet: "menus" },
  { path: "submenu2", component: SubmenuComponent, outlet: "menus" },
  { path: "submenu3", component: SubmenuComponent, outlet: "menus" },
  ...
];
```

I tried to use the wild card `**` to match everything **starting** with *submenu* in the following way. Sadly, I seem not to match anything that way and get no routing at all.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "submenu**", component: SubmenuComponent, outlet: "menus" },
  //{ path: "submenu1", component: SubmenuComponent, outlet: "menus" },
  //{ path: "submenu2", component: SubmenuComponent, outlet: "menus" },
  //{ path: "submenu3", component: SubmenuComponent, outlet: "menus" },
  ...
];
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following ?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "submenu1", component: SubmenuComponent, outlet: "menus" },
  { path: "submenu2", redirectTo: 'submenu'},
  { path: "submenu3", redirectTo: 'submenu'},
];
```

or if it doesn't bother you to put a router listener on app component:

```
ngOnInit() {

        if (isPlatformBrowser) {
            this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
                .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
                .subscribe(() => {
                    if(this.router.url.startsWith('submenu'){
                        this.router.navigate(['submenu1']);
                    };
                });
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider making the 1,2,3 parameters instead of part of the route string: `submenu/1`, `submenu/2` and so on. That way your route configuration can just be

```
{ path: "submenu/:id", component: SubmenuComponent, outlet: "menus" },
```

Here is an example of one of mine:

```
    RouterModule.forChild([
        {
            path: 'messages/:id',
            component: MessageComponent,
            outlet: 'popup'
        }
    ])
```

Then I navigate to it this way:

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: { popup: ['messages', 7]}}]);
```

But a `routerLink` would also work.

The result is: `http://localhost:3000/welcome(popup:messages/7)` in the browser address bar.

Comment: That would be great. Sadly, I get the issue that hte slashes are replaced by "*%2F*" and [the solution by "*\**"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36608461/1525840) as [described here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8049) seems not to work. I'll keep googlearching in hope that I'll find something but it seems that I'll have to live with gazillion separate routes.

Comment: I'm not sure the comments in the blog post you referenced are still applicable. I just tried this with one of my routes and get this: `http://localhost:3000/welcome(popup:messages/7)`. There is no escaping being done. How are you navigating to the routes?