# QueryParams within RouterLink not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-routing, routerlink

I am passing dynamically generated URL with `queryParams` inside `[routerLink]` and it breaks routes.

i.e: `this.url = '/question/ask?details=1'`

```
<a [routerLink]="url"> {{ data.name }}</a>
```

When we mouseover it looks something like this `#/question/ask%3Fdetails%3D1` and breaks when we click.

P.S: Since I am passing dynamic URLs so passing `[queryParams]` separetly not possible however this works:

```
<a [routerLink]="/question/ask" [queryParams]={details: 1}> {{ data.name }}</a>
```

Any solution we can pass a complete URL with `queryParams` inside `[routerLink]`?

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer:**

Whatever you pass inside `routerLink` directive will end up calling `encodeURI` function on value that have been passed.

---

**Long Answer**

This happens because when you directly pass whole url inside `routerLink` it eventually call [`serializeUrl`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.0.7/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L230) method of `routerLink` directive. Which call `serialize` method of `urlSerializer`. The implementation of serialize method looks like below. [code link here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.0.7/packages/router/src/url_tree.ts#L284-L292)

```
serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
    const segment = `/${serializeSegment(tree.root, true)}`;
    const query = serializeQueryParams(tree.queryParams);
    const fragment =
        typeof tree.fragment === `string` ? `#${encodeUriFragment(tree.fragment !)}` : '';

    return `${segment}${query}${fragment}`;
}

export function encodeUriFragment(s: string): string {
    return encodeURI(s);
}
```

---

Possible workaround to solve this issue could be, decode the URL by using angular `Router`'s inbuilt method called as `parseUrl` method. Which basically help you to find `root` of the `URL` and `params`, `queryParams`, etc.

**Component**

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  url: any;
  formattedUrl: any;
  params: any = {};

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.urlDecoder();
  }

  urlDecoder() {
    this.url = '/a?i=1 a';
    let parsedUrl = this.router.parseUrl(this.url);
    console.log(parsedUrl)
    const g: UrlSegmentGroup = parsedUrl.root.children[PRIMARY_OUTLET];
    const s: UrlSegment[] = g.segments;
    this.formattedUrl = `${s.map(p => p.path).join('/')}`; // this is required to combine all continued segment
    this.params = parsedUrl.queryParams;
  }
}
```

**Html**

```
<a [routerLink]="formattedUrl" [queryParams]="params">
  Link Here
</a>
```

[**Demo Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnzdcn)

Comment: cant we use `decodeURI` to decode URL so that it decode special chars. Thanks for that detail ans though.

Comment: @KamranKhatti no we can't, rather you can pass your own urlSerializer implementation by overriding `serialize` method, but rather I'd prefer you to do it in this way. Did you check the stackblitz?

Comment: I did but I think you missed something, its not rendering the value of `formattedUrl`

Comment: @KamranKhatti give me a moment. Just fixing missing part. Thanks for heads up

Comment: That same solution I already did I am looking for any short solution which I am thinking angular should have coz the requirement is a regular not a special one so there should be a better solution instead of hacky or workaround. Thanks for your ans I am upvoting it though.

Comment: @KamranKhatti better way to solve this solution could be create a component / directive, that will do all work for you :)

Comment: @KamranKhatti simplified version could look like this, please check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdcdxc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). I'd love to update answer if you like it.

Comment: @KamranKhatti did you get chance to check the updated stackblitz?

Comment: Yeah I did but that is pretty much same I am trying to avoid playing with URL (parsing and separating queryParam  etc), lets see if I get a better option still trying to get a better one otherwise this will be the ultimate solution.

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597832/angular2-routerlink-breaks-routes-by-replacing-slash-with-2f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174782/discussion-between-kamran-khatti-and-pankaj-parkar).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
this.url = ['/question', 'ask']; //Maybe without slash: ['question', 'ask']
this.query = {details: 1};
```

Html:

```
<a [routerLink]="url" [queryParams]="query">Somewhere</a>
```

Comment: Read my complete question what I have asked