# In Angular localize-router if path contains multiple slashes / change language breaks

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm using Angular 7 and localize router v2.0RC.
I'm facing an issue if the path of my route is like this:

```
[{
  path: 'parentX',
  children: [
   {
     path: 'y/z'
     component: AnyComponent
   }
  ]
}]
```

when I use the `changeLanguage` method from `LocalizeRouterService` the URL in browser changes but all slashes after `parentX` will be url encoded (escaped) and replaced by `%2F` which causes not to match any route in the list.
Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to do this:

```
[{
  path: 'parentX',
  children: [
   {
     path: 'y',
     children: [
       {
        path: 'z',
        component: AnyComponent
       }
     ]
   }
  ]
}]
```