# how to use Forward slashes as URL in angular 5 router

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Have some special requirement like double slashes must be in URL like below

`http://localhost:3000/search//37.77/-122.419/nearby`

Note : That **double forward slashes** after the `search` is required.

What I have tried

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SearchpagesComponent ,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'search//:lat/:lng/:filter', loadChildren: './search/search.module#SearchModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Have enabled log by `{ enableTracing: true }` and debugged. it's not considering full URL only considering till `http://localhost:3000/parking` and as that not matching with any routes its redirecting to `http://localhost:3000`

How can I achieve component load with a double slash in URL?

---

Edited

It will also work if its redirect to similar URL without slashes so at least component load.
Like below URL will redirect to 
`http://localhost:3000/search//37.77/-122.419/nearby` ---> `http://localhost:3000/search/37.77/-122.419/nearby`

Found similar issue on angular repo https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32853

Comment: Why are the double forward slashes required for the `search` path? That might actually break your routes.

Comment: refer this link,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597832/angular2-routerlink-breaks-routes-by-replacing-slash-with-2f

Comment: @Edric Migrating existing project with angular and the current url's are like above, and that URL's promoted and running many campaigns and well indexed by search engines

Comment: @DixitSavaliya check accepted answer comments it's not working with child routes.