# How do we add a navigation to a mat-chip in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I am receiving Template parse errors: with the code below , what is the right implementation ?

#cODE

```
 <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection">
                            <mat-chip [routerLink]="['templates/,{{ template.name }} ,/edit']" *ngFor="let template of associated_template;" [selectable]="selectable">
                            {{ template.name }}
                            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                            </mat-chip>
                            <input [matChipInputFor]="chipList" [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
                          </mat-chip-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must not mix property binding and string interpolation

```
<mat-chip [routerLink]="['templates/', template.name, '/edit']" *ngFor="let template of associated_template;" [selectable]="selectable">
```

Comment: @R Pasha why is that the edit on the url becames %2Fedit ?

Comment: after navigation

Comment: what is value of `template.name`

Comment: it is suppoed to be template.id sir here is the final <mat-chip [routerLink]="['/templates/', template.id, '/edit']"

and the result url is /templates/98/%2Fedit

Comment: it has something to do with your route configuration. check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597832/angular2-routerlink-breaks-routes-by-replacing-slash-with-2f

Comment: what would be the solution SIr ?

Comment: change `:id` to `*id` in your route config